# PDO retriving ID

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been stuck at this for awhile now, but basically I'm trying to create a function in PHP that retrives a users ID by passing in the users username into the funciton.

I'm using PHP's PDO and its probably something smacking me in the face but I'm getting the following error:

"Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/swinkidc/public_html/studentreach/core/user.php on line 8"

Index.php -

```
include 'core/user.php';
$user->getUserID("alex");
```

core/user.php -

```
include('connect.php');

class user extends database{

    public function getUserID($user){
        $query = $_link->prepare('SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :user');
    }

}
```

core/connect.php

```
    class database {    

    protected $_link;


    public function __construct (){
       $_link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=swinkidc_student", "swinkidc_student", "");
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to access instance variables with `$this`:

```
$this->_link = new PDO(...)
// ...
$this->_link->prepare(...)
```

Check the [Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) for more.

Comment: Oh my god. I knew it was something so simple. Thank you!